# Could not find method include() for arguments [:app] on root project 'myProject'

Tags: android-studio, gradlew

I'm trying to create my first project in android studio, I'm on a mac, FYI.  When I build settings.gradle, I get a failed build.  **Note:**  Please don't mark this as a duplicate, see below I have links to two other SO questions that didn't fix the problem.

My settings.gradle file contents:
`include ':app'`, but I've also tried `include 'app'` based on the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885964/could-not-find-method-include-for-arguments-app-on-root-project), with no difference in result.

The Gradle Console ends with `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, but the debug window shows `BUILD FAILED`:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57079,suspend=y,server=n
>   "-Dgradle.home=/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10"
>   -Dtools.jar=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
>   -javaagent:/Users/username/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio2.1/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar
>   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/groovy-all-2.4.4.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/ant-1.9.3.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/ant-launcher-1.9.3.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-base-services-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-cli-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-core-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-docs-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-launcher-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-messaging-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-model-core-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-native-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-open-api-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-resources-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-ui-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-announce-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-antlr-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-build-comparison-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-build-init-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-code-quality-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-dependency-management-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-ear-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-ide-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-ide-native-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-ivy-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-jacoco-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-javascript-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-jetty-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-language-groovy-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-language-java-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-language-jvm-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-language-native-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-language-scala-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-maven-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-osgi-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-base-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-jvm-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-native-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-platform-play-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-plugin-development-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-plugin-use-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-plugins-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-publish-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-reporting-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-http-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-s3-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-resources-sftp-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-scala-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-signing-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-sonar-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-test-kit-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-testing-native-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/gradle-tooling-api-builders-2.10.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-2.10/lib/plugins/ivy-2.2.0.jar:/Applications/Android
>   Studio.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
>   --build-file /Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/settings.gradle
>   objc[64642]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib.
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. Connected to the
>   target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57079', transport: 'socket'
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/settings.gradle'
>     line: 1
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
>
> Could not find method include() for arguments [:app] on root project 'myProject'.
>
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 0.952 secs
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '[obscuredIP]:57079', transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Per the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886259/could-not-find-method-include-for-arguments-app-on-root-project-android-stu), I have done `./gradlew assembleRelease` both in android studio's terminal and in my mac's terminal.  in Android Studio terminal, I get a successful build, but on the mac's terminal, I get:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'username'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'username'.
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.682 secs
```

In case it helps, this is the output on mac's terminal for ./gradlew tasks --all:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks --all
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build. [incubating]
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files. [incubating]

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'username'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'username'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'username'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'username'.
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'username'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'username'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'username'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'username'.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.674 secs
```

Comment: Most likely, your project is not configured correctly as an Android gradle project. The relevant file is **build.gradle** in the 'root' directory ('kmckinley'). But the error shows that Android Studio was looking at  '/Users/username/AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/'. Maybe you can explain where this discrepancy comes from.

Comment: @AlexCohn, I guess you were essentially right.  I ended up finding the Analyze->Inspect Code, which showed I was referencing a non-latest build (compilesdkversion was 23 instead of 24), I worked through everything that inspector suggested about updating the sdk version and rebuilt the project, then it worked.  thanks.  Write up an answer incorporating these things and I'll probably accept it.

Comment: error message "Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project" means that the working directory is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Analyze->Inspect Code menu to show code inspection issues.  In this case, the problem was that the build.gradle file was referencing a different compilesdkversion than other places in the project.

Analyze->Inspect Code is very useful, use it!

Answer (score 0):

It looked like the Android studio had bad settings of current project. In my case it looked like it had setting from othre project. The dependencies of project properties (Ctr+Shift+S) was diffrent from dependecies in build.gradle file. (Analyse showed me nothing wrong and from console it worked). I just:

1. closed the project
2. removed the .gradle, .idea and build directory
3. and opened project again.

After that, it builds project without problem.